# What to do when you have a emotionally and physically abusive Mother in Islam?

Tags: quran

I am a teenager who is going through a emotional crisis. My dad 2 years ago got really sick and till now he isn’t really being the part of our family and daily life affairs because of his health issues.

So one thing to keep in mind is that I come from a really conservative, influential(the place where I live)and wealthy family I have seen other parents in my family who have dis agreed to even get their daughter and sons to get married because of property reasons. Some of them got married in secret because for years they had been begging their parents to let them get married as they have aged so much, some of them are over 35 years old and still haven’t got married yet because of their parents not agreeing.

In my case my mother started looking into all our family matters. I am a only child who was always adored by everyone around me but no one knew that what goes on inside our house. When I was young like 4 or 5 years old my mom used to slap me or get mad at me for no reason whereas my dad always used to calm her down so I don’t get hurt so because of this she always used to say my dad is spoiling me a lot.now that times have changed considering that my dad is basically bed ridden my mom has control over everything.

My mother curses at me all the time and says she regrets the day I was born and that if she knew I would turn out like this, a person who always adores her dads family more than her family side she would have killed me in the first place. I always struggled with my studies which resulted in my mother sending me to at least 3 tuitions at a time. She always had this narrative that I would never be like my other cousins and all and that I’m useless. I remember when I was young she always used to prioritise my other cousins and I would be left out.

Now that I am in grade 10 and entering grade 11 in just a short amount of time as I am done with my final exams i am still abused emotionally, psychologically and physically. I get slapped and get things thrown at me regularly, she curses the day I was born and that I should die. She prays to Allah that I get the worst situations and that Allah (S.W.T) would punish me for things I’ve not even done. We get into arguments all the time and I accept the fact that I also talk back but nowadays my mothers taunts and harsh words have gotten to the point that I cry in my salah all time and I even wish to die.

I am depressed but I still try to offer my salah regularly especially in the blessed month of Ramadan. As that is the only source which makes me feel a little bit better.

My mother taunts me about my looks and weight. I’m basically a laughingstock in my household, except my dad who actually cares about me but because of having a short temper I really don’t tell him about what my mother does to me.

I would like to get some good advice and would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please edit the question or post another question without all the unnecessary context.